# Looking for similar functionality in java

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

Easy Http library for C sharp has a method to post data to url,

```
var customer = new Customer(); 
    customer.Name = "Joe"; 
    customer.Email = "joe@smith.com";
    var http = new HttpClient();
    http.Post("url", customer, HttpContentTypes.ApplicationJson);
```

Looking for some library to post data to a URL for Java.

Comment: You've added the tag `apache-httpclient-4.x` - did you bother to google that one?

Comment: I read so many but I was not sure how those things work for me @AndersR.Bystrup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache's [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for creating the basic `HTTP` operations in Java.

For example, a `POST` would look like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://some-web-site");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Joe"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "joe@smith.com"));
httPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is a great, free API for doing `POST`s and `GET`s to URLs.

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formParams.add("requestXML",requestXML);
formParams.add("version","1");

WebResource webResource = Client.create().resource("http://myurl.org/");
String response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(String.class, formParams);
```